# Same query but different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm faced with a big query that is generated in a string and executed with "OPEN pCursor FOR vQuery" and I'm trying to get the query out of the string variable and as a proper "compilable" query.

I'm having this problem where a different table is query depending on a variable

```
vQuery := 'SELECT ...';

IF pVar = 1 Then
    vQuery := vQuery || ' FROM table1';
ELSE
    vQuery := vQuery || ' FROM table2';
END IF

vQuery := vQuery || ' WHERE ...';
```

The two tables have pretty much the same column name. Is there a way to have this as a single query

```
OPEN Pcursorout FOR
SELECT ... FROM CASE WHEN pVar = 1 THEN table1 ELSE table1 END WHERE ...;
```

Or I'm stuck at having two queries?

```
IF pVar = 1 Then
    OPEN Pcursorout FOR SELECT ... FROM table1 WHERE ...;
ELSE
    OPEN Pcursorout FOR SELECT ... FROM table2 WHERE ...;
END IF
```

The select and where part are large and exactly the same for both table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) and use your variable pVar to only include the results from one query in the result set.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, ..., t1.col10
FROM table1 t1
WHERE pVar = 1 and ...
UNION
SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2, ..., t2.col10
FROM table1 t2
WHERE pVar <> 1 and ...
```

This isn't exactly what you asked about -- not being required to have duplicate lists of columns for the two select statements -- but I think it might capture your intent. It will require that the columns selected by both queries have the same datatype so there will be a (somewhat weak) constraint that the columns of both query results are the same. For example, you won't be able to add a new column to one query but not the other.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using UNION / UNION ALL  to unite both queries? The requirement for using UNION/UNION ALL is that all SELECTs being united must return columns with the same names.

So if you have

```
SELECT t.f1, 
       t.f2, 
       t.f3
FROM   t
WHERE ...

and your other query is

SELECT q.f1,
       q.f2,
       q.f3
FROM q
WHERE ...
```

you can have both running as a single SQL statement with UNION:

```
SELECT t.f1, 
       t.f2, 
       t.f3
FROM   t
WHERE ...

UNION

SELECT q.f1,
       q.f2,
       q.f3
FROM q
WHERE ...
```

Keep in mind that if you need to return columns that exist in one table but not in the other, you can still use UNION, just return NULL and name the column correspondingly to the column name in the table that has it.

Comment: Actually after read it properly, this is a very good suggestion, just add a first clause in the WHERE of every SELECT to validate which one is running. SELECT t... FROM t WHERE pvar1 = 1 AND ... UNION SELECT q... FROM q WHERE pvar1 <> 1 AND ...

Comment: @Veverke - I thought the OP was trying to avoid duplicating the select and were clauses though? If you don't mind duplicating them (making them harder to maintain) then why both with a union; just stick with two queries?

Comment: @AlexPoole: indeed. The union was suggested since he asked to have them all executing in a single SQL statement. Or this was what I understood...

Comment: @AlexPoole: by the way: if the issue here is "saving coding-time" and issuing the queries in a single SQL statement is not a requirement - then I would use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and parameterize as much as I want the SQL string (including FROM, WHERE clauses). He would define the "skeleton" of the query, and the rest would come as parameters (binding variables) at run time.

Comment: There seem to be a few things going on, which confused me a bit; wants to avoid dynamic SQL so its compilable (maybe to spot errors early); wants a single statement; and the bit I may have incorrectly inferred from the last sentence of the question, wants to avoid duplication of the select/where clauses. At least I seem to be incorrect from your interpretation and the accepted answer. Well, the OP seems to be happy, which is the main thing!?

Comment: I think he has the last word, yes =]. Thank you for reviewing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a kludge and you might need to look at the performance impact, but you could use an inline view that unions the two base tables, with a flag on each part that you then compare to your variable

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as var, table1.*
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as var, table2.*
    FROM table2
) t
WHERE t.var = pVar
AND ...;
```

Using an inline view means you don't have to duplicate the main select-list or the `where` clause etc. If the tables have different columns then you can (and maybe should anyway) only select the columns in the inner queries that will be referenced in the outer select-list.